# Check failed: !initialized_

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-6.0-marshmallow

In my Xamarin Forms App, I'm receiving the following error:

> art/runtime/fault_handler.cc:117] Check failed: !initialized_

And after that the app crashes with no other message in very random situations.

My device:

- Android Marshmallow
- Motorola G3
- Xamarin   4.0.3.214 (0dd817c)
- Xamarin.Android   6.0.3.5 (a94a03b)
- Xamarin.iOS   9.6.1.8 (3a25bf1)

Any ideas?

Have a nice day

Comment: Maybe have a look at the suggested solutions https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35739 E.g. set traget sdk version to 23 explicitly

Answer (score 5):

Go to your Adb console:

In VisualStudio -> Tools -> Android -> Android Adb Command Prompt...

Enter: adb shell setprop debug.mono.env MONO_DEBUG=soft-breakpoints

Also, it appears the setting resets and you have to run it again after restart.

Comment: How to set the MONO_DEBUG back to de default value after running this? I tried `adb shell setprop debug.mono.env MONO_DEBUG=hard-breakpoints` but it count "hard-breakpoints" as a invalid option

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution from [Xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/171282/#Comment_171282):

> Go into your Application Properties and change "Target Android Version" to "23" explicetly.
>
> There seems to be a bug in that when set to "Use Compile using SDK version", the manifest doesn't actually identify "23" anywhere. I'm
>   not exactly sure what API is actually being targeted with that
>   setting.
>
> Essentially, if you have Use Compile using SDK version, your manifest will only reflect your Minimum Android Target (and my
>   assumption is that the Target is ALSO that).
>
> If you explicetly set the target to 23, you'll see the following added to your manifest.
>
> android:targetSdkVersion="23"

Comment: I´ve read that post also, but the error is still happening and I do not have a clue what else can be. Thank you #Giorgi

Comment: @Lug: Did you try this suggestion? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/191765/#Comment_191765